# How do I give an "identifier" to a view controller within my storyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

The `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:` method requires that the view controller  I pass have an identifier. I went to my storyboard and clicked on my view controller, but I see no option to set the identifier. Where exactly do I find this option?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

As the Image suggests! Hope it helps!

[image]

Then to use it you call:

```
[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"YourViewControllerID"];
```

Comment: can i set it programmatically please help

Comment: @user9395315 No you can't set the storyboardID programmatically

Answer (score 16):

Updated for XCode 8 and Swift 3.

`instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` is now **instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:)**.

Setting the storyboard ID:
[image]

Comment: More on instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:)

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistoryboard/1616214-instantiateviewcontroller

Answer (score 5):

In the *identity inspector* there is a field *Storyboard ID*. You could enter the class name here and then use this identifier in `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:`.