# How to pass string value from one .m file to another .m file in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have multiple string value in one .m file and i want to access these file  to another .m file to use value in file.

Comment: You should refer this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/22934200/3883040.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing Data between View Controllers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you wants to pass data from ViewControlerOne to ViewControllerTwo try these..

do these in ViewControlerOne.h

```
 @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *str1;
```

do these in ViewControllerTwo.h

```
 @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *str2;
```

Synthesize str2 in ViewControllerTwo.m

```
@interface ViewControllerTwo ()
@end
@implementation ViewControllerTwo
@synthesize str2;
```

do these in ViewControlerOne.m

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
 {
   [super viewDidLoad];

  // Data or string you wants to pass in ViewControllerTwo..
  self.str1 = @"hello world";

 }
```

on the buttons click event do this..

```
-(IBAction)ButtonClicked
{ 
  //Navigation on buttons click event from ViewControlerOne to ViewControlerTwo with transferring data or string..
  ViewControllerTwo *objViewTwo=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewControllerTwo"];
  objViewTwo.str2=str1;
  [self.navigationController pushViewController: objViewTwo animated:YES];
}
```

do these in ViewControllerTwo.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
 [super viewDidLoad];
  NSLog(@"%@",str2);
}
```

Comment: in button clicked event could you tell me please what is "obj"?obj.str2=str1;

Comment: i updated that line..it is object of ViewControllerTwo..

Comment: I got exception when i hit on button ---Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Storyboard (<UIStoryboard: 0x7b72d590>) doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'CustomerDetailViewController''

Comment: @harshrajput  show your code.

Comment: refer these links for giving storyboard Id..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15478411/how-do-i-give-an-identifier-to-a-view-controller-within-my-storyboard and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8295471/storyboard-doesnt-contain-a-view-controller-with-identifier

Comment: - (IBAction)CheckAvailablity:(id)sender {
    CustomerDetailViewController *objViewTwo=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CustomerDetailViewController"];
objViewTwo.getData=_goData;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController: objViewTwo animated:YES];
    
}

Comment: @Sushil on the click event of button i write this code and no segue link on storyboard.Than is shows this error.And also i have no storyboard id set.

Comment: If you are using storyboard, you need to set storyboardID for your `CustomerDetailViewController`. Follow the link in  @krushnsinh's comment.

Comment: you gave Navigation Controller to your first view controller??and set storyboard id..In my code second view controllers name is ViewControllerTwo and its storyboard id is also ViewControllerTwo..

Comment: Thanks this code works but in my case .

Answer (score -1):

With the following two ways you can achieve this, 
1)  You can create public property in .h file. 
2)  Can also use delegate or notification to pass data between controllers.