# How to navigate ViewController when clicking button in alertView

Tags: swift, swift2

Given the code below, when I click the "Accept" button, it doesn't navigate to `SecondViewController`, it only shows a black screen. Any help appreciated.

```
   let alertController = UIAlertController(title: tit!, message: "Book Now!", preferredStyle: .Alert)
   let declineAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Decline", style: .Cancel, handler: nil)
   alertController.addAction(declineAction)

   let acceptAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Accept", style: .Default) { (_) -> Void in
        let nv=SecondViewController()
        self.presentViewController(nv, animated:true, completion:nil)
    }
   presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
   alertController.addAction(acceptAction)
```

Answer (score 2):

To open any `UIViewController` just must `instantiate` it. And what you are doing is just creating the object of the class.

To do so:

```
let nv = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("storyboardidentifier") as! SecondViewController
self.presentViewController(nv, animated:true, completion:nil)
```

This is open your `UIViewController` as wants!

Comment: storyboardidentifier means mystoryboard name.is it correct

Comment: @Honestraj19 Make sure you have given 'identifier' to your `UIViewController` from `StoryBoard`

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15478411/how-do-i-give-an-identifier-to-a-view-controller-within-my-storyboard

Answer (score 0):

Create a segue link from your current view controller to the SecondViewController and give it an identifier in the storyboard and you can use the following code

```
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Options", message: "Book Now!", preferredStyle: .Alert)

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Accept", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { (alertAction) -> Void in
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("FirstToSecond", sender: self)

    }))
    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Note: your first view controller will be the anchor.

If you have embedded your SecondViewController in a navigation controller and also want to pass the value, you can add the following

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "FirstToSecond" {
        let nav = segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController
        let svc = nav.viewControllers[0] as! SecondViewController
        //svc.delegate = self //uncomment this if you need to set a delegate as well
        svc.value = ""
    }
}
```

This is using xCode 7 & Swift 2. Hope this helps :)

Comment: I want to set time delay for my alert controller .is it possible

Comment: You will have to use NSTimeInterval for that

Comment: u can refer to these questions
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25951980/swift-do-something-every-x-minutes &
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24034544/dispatch-after-gcd-in-swift