# Swift: Constant ' ' used before being initialized

Tags: swift, swift3, constants

I'm attempting to pass data to a label on my second VC through the function `func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView)`.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {

    print("Annotation selected")


    if let annotation = view.annotation as? POIAnnotations {

       let destVC : ShopDetailViewController

        destVC.shopName.text = annotation.title!

        print("Your annotation title is: \(annotation.title!)")

    }

}
```

When I set `shopName.text` to `annotation.title`, I get an error stating:

> Constant 'destVC' used before being initialized.

I'm not quite sure what's going wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have only declared the variable destVC, not initialized it. You need to instansiate the variable, either directly or through the storyboard before using it, e.g. this:

```
let destVC = ShopDetailViewController()
```

or

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MyStoryboardName", bundle: nil)
let destVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ShopDetailViewController") as! ShopDetailViewController
```

Answer (score 3):

The error is clearly saying that you have not initialized the constant `destVC` yet and you are trying to use its property `shopName`. So initializing the `destVC` before accessing its property will remove the error.

If you are using a `storyboard`

```
let destVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "IdentifierOfVC") as! ShopDetailViewController
```

If you are using an `xib`

```
let destVC = ShopDetailViewController()
```

Comment: wouldn't `let destVC : ShopDetailViewController` be initializing it? How else would I initialize it?

Comment: @daanyyaal If you doesn't know how to set identifier of viewController in storyboard check this so answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/15478575/6433023