# Use func from different view controller swift

Tags: swift

I uses storyboard to build the layout. I am trying to access func in `firstViewController` from `secondViewController` but when I use the following code to access it I will always get "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" no matter what function or outlet I have tried to access I always get the same error. Did I miss anything or am I doing it wrongly?

`done` is  located in `secondViewController`

```
func done(){
    let vc =  firstViewController()
    vc.drawCircle(locationX: 0, locationY: 0)
}
```

`drawCircle` is  located in `firstViewController`

```
func drawCircle(locationX:CGFloat, locationY: CGFloat) {
    let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: locationX, y: locationY, width: radius, height: radius), cornerRadius: 50).cgPath
    combinePath.addPath(path)
    layer.path = combinePath

    if thickness>0{
        layer.strokeColor = UIColor(red: rColor, green: gColor, blue: bColor, alpha: 1).cgColor
        layer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor

        layer.lineWidth = thickness
    }
    imageView.layer.addSublayer(layer)

}
```

Comment: Are you using storyboard?

Comment: show the code for the drawCircle function, also specify whether you are using storyboards, nibs, or just creating view controllers in code

Comment: @Ray_Soham Yes I am using storyboard

Comment: @Scriptable I am using storyboard and I have added the code for drawCircle please have a look at it thank you

Comment: Ok, I think @mahmut's answer will solve your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is due to the reference to `imageView` in function `drawCircle` because it means that in order for it to run, the `firstViewController` must be fully initialised and on-screen for the `imageView` to be "hooked up" to the User Interface.

Are both the `firstViewController` and `secondViewController` supposed to be on-screen at the same time?

To solve your problem you should drag two `Container View`s into your storyboard.  The Custom Class (in the identity inspector) for each Container View should be firstViewController and secondViewController respectively.

Then when you are on-screen, both controllers will be initialised, and `imageView` will be hooked up properly (the Implicitly Unwrapped Optional will be non-nil).
This means you will then be able to safely call the `drawCircle` method.

Comment: firstViewController and secondViewController are not supposed to be on-screen at the same time

Comment: OK.  In that case you need to update a value in a shared data structure (a model object) with the location (0,0), and a Bool shouldDrawCircle = true.  Then in the firstViewController, in viewDidAppear, call the drawCircle method and then reset the shouldDrawCircle boolean.

Comment: My app its not totally completed yet but I just tried the method you said and I think this is just what I need. thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 1):

Default constructor does not create UI component from storyboard (IBOutlet, IBAction,..)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using storyboards, give an identifier to view controller and use this:

```
if let firstVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "firstViewController") as? firstViewController {
    firstVC.drawCircle(locationX: 0, locationY: 0)
}
```

Comment: Hi I have just tried this but it just give me "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT" error and in the log it says " Storyboard (<UIStoryboard: 0x1c4470140>) doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'firstViewController"

Comment: Did you give an identifier to firstViewController in Identity Inspector?

Comment: there isn't a identifier for firstViewController.

Comment: I am not sure this will help but before firstViewController I actually have another viewController called viewController.

Comment: You must give an identifier. If you don't know how to do it, this answer helps : https://stackoverflow.com/a/45723662/5130481

Comment: I have added the identifier but now it gives me the same error as before where it says "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Comment: I think this isn't the cause of the error. You might missed something in your code.

Comment: Noted. Thank you very much for your help.